# Is there a Java collection whose objects are unique (as in a set) but has the ability to get the index/position of a certain object(as in a list)?

Tags: list, set, unique

I have an ordered, unique, set of objects. I am currently using a TreeSet in order to get the ordering correct. However, sets do not have the ability to get index.

My current implementation is fine, but not necessarily intuitive.

```
TreeSet<T> treeSet = new TreeSet<T>(Comparable c);
// Omitted: Add items to treeSet //
int index = new ArrayList<T>(treeSet)().indexOf(object);
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`treeSet.headSet(object).size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#headSet%28E%29) should do the trick:

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SortedSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    String first = "index 0";
    String second = "index 1";
    treeSet.add(first);
    treeSet.add(second);

    int one = treeSet.headSet(second).size();

    System.out.println(one);
    // 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Unfortunately it's no faster than iterating through the tree by hand – Java doesn't cache subtree sizes so it's O(n) instead of O(log n) as it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem of finding element at a certain position in a TreeMap. I enhanced the tree with weights that allow accessing elements by index and finding elements at indexes.
The project is called indexed-tree-map https://github.com/geniot/indexed-tree-map . The implementation for finding index of an element or element at an index in a sorted map is not based on linear iteration but on a tree binary search. Updating weights of the tree is also based on climbing up the tree to the root. So no linear iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have such a thing. Here are a few suggestions what you could do:

1. Leave it as it is, since this is not as bad as it could be ;)
2. Use an iterator to go trough your elements
3. Write a wrapper class which extends TreeSet and add the get functionality.
4. Checkout [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and look if they have something like this (I haven't used it, so I can't tell, sorry!)
5. create an array `Object[] arrayView = mySet.toArray();` and then get the elements from that (this is kinda stupid in terms of performance and memory)